# Found broken link in help centre. Who should I notify?

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) section of the FAQ the link "Writing the perfect question by Jon Skeet" is broken. I am unsure as to who handles these things, and even if I should be posting this here. I'm not that familiar with meta. I figured this might qualify as a bug report.

Comment: The general meta site is probably where you want to let them know.

Comment: I've updated the link to one that looks current.